# What do empty (missing) values in the output of PCA or factor analysis mean in R?

Tags: r, pca, factor-analysis

I am doing factor analysis with `factanal` in R and observe empty spaces in the loadings table:

```
factanal(x = ~V1 + V2 + V3 + V4 + V5, factors = 2, data = airfoil_self_noise)

Uniquenesses:
   V1    V2    V3    V4    V5 
0.898 0.005 0.005 0.995 0.394 

Loadings:
   Factor1 Factor2
V1 -0.319         
V2  0.877  -0.474 
V3          0.997 
V4                
V5  0.754  -0.194
```

Here, I have no idea what empty space means in Factor1-V3, Factor1-V4, Factor2-V1, and Factor2-V4. Weren't they supposed to be filled with some numbers, like with 0?

The same sometimes happens in PCA using `principal` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [R documentation on `factanal`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/factanal.html):

> The `print` method (documented under [`loadings`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/loadings.html)) follows the factor analysis convention of drawing attention to the patterns of the results, so the default precision is three decimal places, and small loadings are suppressed.

From [the R documentation on loadings](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/loadings.html):

> Small loadings are conventionally not printed (replaced by spaces), to draw the eye to the pattern of the larger loadings.

The default value of `cutoff` ("loadings smaller than this (in absolute value) are suppressed") is .1, so you can infer that the absolute values in those spaces are $<0.1$.

If you want exact values, you can wrap your `factanal()` function in `print(...,cutoff=0)`.

Answer (score 3):

By default, `factanal` only prints loadings that are above 0.1 in absolute value. The `cutoff` argument can be used to change this.

So, the blanks mean -0.1 < loading < 0.1